# netstat shows ESTABLISHED connection between same ip:port pair

Tags: windows, networking, netstat

I am on Windows Server 2016 Standard. See netstat output below (IP replaced):

```
C:\Users\user>netstat -an|findstr "55559"
  TCP    1.2.3.4:55559     1.2.3.4:55559     ESTABLISHED
```

What does it mean? I was searching the Net for answers but found nothing.
Can somebody explain?

UPDATE:

1. Process1 was listening on port 55559.
2. Process2 connected to it from the same machine (but on its public IP: 10.x.y.z).

(Process1 is an IIS AppPool, which besides its normal OWIN WebApi interface opens an additional tcp service socket on port 55559 for internal purposes.)

3. Process1 was terminated by IIS resource management features (not used for a "long time").

The result is the situation described in the question.

The problem is: Process1 cannot be restarted (on first request by IIS),
because its initialization fails (cannot bind on port 55559 because another process uses it.)

The another process is: Process2! Why? How?

Comment: As a first step run ```netstat``` with the ```-abon``` switches so you can see which process and executable are responsible for this connection. You can also try to check with Sysinternals TCPView (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview).

Comment: 1.2.3.4 doesn't happen to 127.x.y.z does it?

Comment: @YisroelTech The process (X) is known. Another process (Y) listened on port 55559 and X supposed to connect to it. Exit of process Y resulted in the mentioned situation.

Comment: @FrankThomas No, but 10.x.y.z.

Comment: It seems like you know a lot more about the situation than what you write (the specific application and protocol, etc.) If you want someone to answer you, I'd suggest you write everything you know about it.

Comment: can you disconnect the extra TCP session using the globals.asax application_stop event? that seems like it would be the proper solution.

Comment: @FrankThomas Promising suggestion, thank you! I am using OWIN Web Api 2 app, there is no application_stop event here. Any suggestions where to find an analog event in this environment where I can implement your solution?

Comment: see if this alternative to globals.asax works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705830/how-to-implement-global-asax-events-by-owin

Comment: Following the ````global.asax```` track @FrankThomas suggested I found a ````CancellationToken```` available in ````OwinContext```` associated with ````host.OnAppDisposing```` key to which I can register and my code gets called on shutdown. Thanks!